# Group distinct count() on a single field in a single request

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Is there a way to get different counts on a single field from a single document ?

Here is a schema for a document `User`

```
UserSchema: {
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  created_at: { type: Date, default: now }
}
```

I would like to get every Users created the 01/05/2013 and the 06/08/2013, maybe i'll need to count more different dates.

Can i get these datas on a sigle `count()` or should i get all the Users with a `find()` then count it using javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`collection.count()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#count-all-documents-that-match-a-query) form which accepts a query, along with the use of [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) and ranges:

```js
db.collection.count({ "$or": [

   { "created_at": 
       {"$gte": new Date("2014-05-01"), "$lt": new Date("2014-05-02") }
   },
   { "created_at": 
       {"$gte": new Date("2013-08-06"), "$lt": new Date("2013-08-07") }
   }

]})
```

Or you can pass that query to `.find()` and use the cursor count from there if that suits your taste.

But then, I **read** your title again, and **distinct** count would be different, and best to use aggregate to get the distinct days:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Match the dates you want to filter
    { "$match": {
        { "$or": [
            { "created_at": {
                "$gte": new Date("2014-05-01"),
                "$lt": new Date("2014-05-02")
            }},
            { "created_at": {
               "$gte": new Date("2013-08-06"), 
               "$lt": new Date("2013-08-07") 
            }}
         ]}
    }},

    // Group on the *whole* day and sum the count
    { "$group": {
         "_id": { 
           "year": { "$year": "$created_at" },
           "month": { "$month": "$created_at" },
           "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$created_at" }
         },
         "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}

])
```

And that would give you a distinct count of the documents for each selected day you had added in your [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) clause.

No need for looping in code.

Comment: Thanks pretty great answer ! I am just wondering, could you explain how mongodb is able to generate a date like this ? Since we send him 2 dates ($gte and $lt), how did you prevent this result ?

Comment: @Ludo not sure I'm catching your meaning here. But if you mean "how does **mongo** generate the dates that are input?", then it doesn't. You are doing that in your client and would use whatever native date construction method you have. Your client driver handles the conversion. The other side is the **ranges** being used. And the **$or** above wraps these as if they were two **separate** conditions. So only dates **within each set** of conditions are selected, and not the dates outside of those **sets**. Very efficient with a use-able index. Hope that clears things up.